# Image Carousel bullet preview image

Tags: html, css

I have code below for an image carousel I made using HTML and CSS. When you hover over one of the three bullets on the bottom, a preview image of the page pops up. There's a slight transition pulling it up and sliding it down. Is there anyway I could keep the transition pulling the image up but when my mouse stops hovering the picture immediately goes away instead of sliding back down? Anything helps, cheers.

```css
.pic {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.carousel {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    widht:100%;
    height:290px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-radius:2px;
  border-color:#FCFCFC;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:290px;
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 100;
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:290px;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align:center;
}

.carousel-control {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding:0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  background-clip: content-box;
  margin:0 auto;
  color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
 
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    color: #4F94CD;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
 .carousel-control:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:transparent;
  border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  top: -4px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  z-index: -5;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3{
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4.5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: relative; /*You are required to do this*/
}
.carousel-indicators .carousel-preview {
    position: absolute;
    width: 108px;
    top: -0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -52px;
    height:0px;
    transition:0.5s all;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-indicators .carousel-preview img {
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:50px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: white;
}
.carousel-indicators li:hover .carousel-preview {
    height:54px;
    top:-50px;
}
.carousel-bullet {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

.HRConnectImage
{width:375px;
padding-top:50px;
display:inline-block;}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

#p
{
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;}


.carousel-control { opacity: 0; }
.carousel:hover .carousel-control { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="carousel"> 
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true" Checked/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="http://wearenorthwest.northwest.ca/departments/humanresources/test/PublishingImages/O%20Gibraltar.PNG">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-2" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
  <img class="pic" src="http://wearenorthwest.northwest.ca/departments/humanresources/test/PublishingImages/ADC.PNG">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-3" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="http://wearenorthwest.northwest.ca/departments/humanresources/test/PublishingImages/CUL.PNG">
      </div>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-1" for="carousel-3">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-1" for="carousel-2">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-2" for="carousel-1">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-2" for="carousel-3">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-3" for="carousel-2">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-3" for="carousel-1">›</label>

      <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-1">●</label> 
            <div class="carousel-preview">
              <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/thumb1.jpg" />
            </div>
         </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-2">●</label> 
            <div class="carousel-preview">
              <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/thumb3.jpg" />
            </div>
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-3">●</label> 
            <div class="carousel-preview">
              <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/thumb2.jpg" />
            </div>
         </li> 

      </ol> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```css
.carousel-indicators .carousel-preview {
   transition:0 all;
}
.carousel-indicators li:hover .carousel-preview {
  transition:0.5s all;
}
```

... to it.

```css
.pic {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.carousel {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width:100%;
    height:290px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-radius:2px;
  border-color:#FCFCFC;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:290px;
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 100;
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:290px;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align:center;
}

.carousel-control {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding:0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  background-clip: content-box;
  margin:0 auto;
  color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
 
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    color: #4F94CD;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
 .carousel-control:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:transparent;
  border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  top: -4px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  z-index: -5;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3{
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4.5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: relative; 
    
    /*You are required to do this*/
}
.carousel-indicators .carousel-preview {
    position: absolute;
    width: 108px;
    top: -0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -52px;
    height:0px;
    transition:0 all;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-indicators .carousel-preview img {
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:50px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: white;
}
.carousel-indicators li:hover .carousel-preview {
    height:54px;
    top:-50px;
    transition:0.5s all;
}
.carousel-bullet {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

.HRConnectImage
{width:375px;
padding-top:50px;
display:inline-block;}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

#p
{
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;}


.carousel-control { opacity: 0; }
.carousel:hover .carousel-control { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="carousel"> 
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true" Checked/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="http://wearenorthwest.northwest.ca/departments/humanresources/test/PublishingImages/O%20Gibraltar.PNG">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-2" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
  <img class="pic" src="http://wearenorthwest.northwest.ca/departments/humanresources/test/PublishingImages/ADC.PNG">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-3" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="http://wearenorthwest.northwest.ca/departments/humanresources/test/PublishingImages/CUL.PNG">
      </div>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-1" for="carousel-3">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-1" for="carousel-2">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-2" for="carousel-1">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-2" for="carousel-3">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-3" for="carousel-2">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-3" for="carousel-1">›</label>

      <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-1">●</label> 
            <div class="carousel-preview">
              <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/thumb1.jpg" />
            </div>
         </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-2">●</label> 
            <div class="carousel-preview">
              <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/thumb3.jpg" />
            </div>
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-3">●</label> 
            <div class="carousel-preview">
              <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/thumb2.jpg" />
            </div>
         </li> 

      </ol> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: That actually slows down the time it takes to go away.

Comment: I think I understood what you want. I'll update in a sec.

Comment: When you hover over the picture there's a slight transition bringing up the image, which is fine. When you hover off, there is also a slight transition making it go away. I want it so if you hover off, the image immediately disappears instead of the transition.

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki, updated. Happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::) Updated again (had a typo. Sorry. :)